# jQuery DataTables: Multiple tables how to copy row without removing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have two tables on the same page.

To copy selected row from table B to table A I use this code:

```
    $('#addButton').click ( function () {
        table1.row.add($('.selected')).draw( false ).node();
    } );
```

This code adds new row to table A, but **removes** copied row from source (B) table.

**Solution.** This problem was solved by suggestion of member Nikos M. Adding **".clone()"** method stopped removing selected row after copying. 
Maybe this should help someone who have had same trouble.  So code should look like this:

```
    $('#addButton').click ( function () {
        table1.row.add($('.selected').clone()).draw( false ).node();
    } );
```

Thank you everyone for participation!

Comment: what should it do and can you share more of your code?

Comment: sth like: `table1.row.add($('.selected').clone()).draw( false ).node();`

Comment: Thank you @Nikos for help! Your solution solved this issue!

Comment: @romansh, great added it as an answer, you can accept it if you will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding comment as answer:

use this:

```
table1.row.add($('.selected').clone()).draw( false ).node();
```

[jQuery.clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method

> **Description:** Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.